# Air Density as a function of Altitude ONLY

Tags: atmospheric-science, density, fluid-statics

I have read this question and doesn't really achieve what I am trying to do.

I am looking for a function of the type

> r(x)=....

Which returns the density of air at altitude **x** for Earth conditions and the changing temperatures that come with altitude difference for the earth like conditions.

I really couldn't find any. Any help appreciated it.

Comment: Something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Standard_Atmosphere) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere)?

Comment: yes something like this, but from what I read it is a mathematical model. So not sure how I can extract a single equation from it with a single input variable.

Comment: The single variable for the atmospheric models is altitude (which is what you want).  This is used to find Temperature, and then pressure/viscosicty are derived from that.  If using the standard approach is not simple enough, then we may need to understand your requirements better.  For example, can you just use a linear interpolation of the altitudes listed in the tables?

Comment: I am trying to use this function as part of a program, a graph (as I understand this to be) or experimental data will be useless for me. This air density function is replaced in an integral to calculate drag of a large object in Earth's atmosphere. I use this equation for the drag https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/drageq.html

Comment: If you are indeed rather dependent on getting the answer "right," I'd recommend implementing a standard atmospheric model, or downloading one which will fit with your project.  They're standards for a reason =)  Any solution outside of using the standards would involve understanding your sensitivities to the accuracy of the results.  It may actually be easier just to borrow an existing implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, the OP referenced wanting to use a simple drag formula for aerodynamic drag, from grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/drageq.html. For altitudes up to 10,000m, the data can be represented by formulas, as in http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a278141.pdf.

The temperature is assumed to change linearly with the altitude $h$:
$$T(h) = T_0 - \alpha h$$
Assuming that air is an ideal gas, this gives a pressure profile is
$$\frac {P(h)}{P_0} = \left(\frac{T(h)}{T_0}\right)^n$$
and the density profile is
$$\frac{\rho(h)}{\rho_0} = \left(\frac{T(h)}{T_0}\right)^{n-1}$$.

In SI units, $$\begin{align}
T_0 &= 288.16\, \text{K}\\
\alpha &= 0.0065\,\text{K/m}\\
P_0 &= 101325\,\text{Pa}\\
\rho_0 &= 1.225\, \text{Kg/m}^3\\
n &= 5.2561
\end{align}$$

For altitudes greater than 10,000m, the variation of temperature against altitude is more complicated, though it can be approximated as a graph containing several straight-line segments, as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_temperature. The constants in the above formulas are different for each segment, and you can't make "one equation" that covers the complete altitude range.

Comment: Awesome answer and very close to what I need, but I am mostly interested for altitudes greater than 20,000m :/

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere) that has been linked to already gives a complete description of how to create the function you are looking for. It starts with a given temperature distribution, which is given as a piecewise linear function in various layers. From there you can then integrate the equations for pressure and density to obtain what you want. Ready-to-use models are also available, see [here](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/atmosmet.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

$$\rho_z=\rho_0exp(-mgz/kT)$$
where
$\rho_z$, $\rho_0$, $m$, $g$, $z$, $k$ and $T$ are density at $z$, density at sea level, mass of air, gravitational acceleration, altitude, Boltzmann constant and temperature, respectively.
* Intermolecular and Surface Forces (Third Edition), Jacob N. Israelachvili, p 27.

Comment: It would be helpful to be explicit about this modeling the case for a constant temperature gas in a uniform gravitational field. The latter assumption is a decent approximation to the conditions of Earth's actual atmosphere (little-gee changes by only a few percent over the height of the atmosphere), but the former is definitely not.